# Synology DS213j how to install Hamachi or LogMeIn service?

Tags: nas, synology, hamachi, logmein

I would like to ask, i have a non-public IP, behind NAT. I would like to access to my home synology server from internet, but i cannot use ssh tunnel.

Is any working "how-to" tutorial about installing service like Hamachi or LogMeIn on Synology NAS server?

Thanks for any advice.

I found these resources, but without luck.

https://secure.logmein.com/labs/#HamachiforLinux

http://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=143&t=30669

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that Hamachi could be used for the VPN, and that can be used without port mapping, setting DMZ, without knowing the "real" (non-VPN) IP Address, etc.  Hamachi can also be installed on Linux, so if you muck around enough, you can probably get it to work on DSM, however...

Given that Synology has a System called QuickConnect that allows you to connect to your NAS from outside via the web using HTTPS under pretty much all conditions, you may not need the VPN support, unless you are hoping for a remote command line.